# What does &array[element] means and why?

Tags: c, mpi

I was coding in MPI using C. I don't understand how the MPI_Send() works or if maybe &array[element] works.

```
MPI_Send(&array[element],element_left,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

here `array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `element = 6` and `element_left = 4`. I understand `array[element]=array[6]=7` but why this function picks 7,8,9,10? I know it will pick 4 elements from the array but why do we need & here and by only giving starting entry `array[6]` how is this function able to pick the next 3 as well?

I thought I have to add one after another using a `for` loop or something, but when I searched something on Google I got this code and after going through so much I still didn't understand. Please help me understand the backwardness of this code.

Comment: `&array[element]` is the address of the value in the array at `element` offset, and is equivalent to `array + element`. So if `element==6`, then `&array[element]` --> `&array[6]` --> address of the 7th item in the array (because the first one is at index 0). In this context, `&` means "take the address of".

Comment: _"why do we need & here"_ - You could use  `array + element` instead if you prefer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&array[element]` is the same expression as `array + element` and means the address of the `element`th element of the array `array`.

The function you call wants this address as the first argument, and takes the number of elements to process as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Most MPI routines take a trio of arguments:

- address of buffer
- count of elements
- datatype of elements

So by `&array[element],element_left,MPI_INT` you specify the `element`s element as the start of the buffer, and then you take `element_left` many integers to send. Kinda strange that you name the count `element_left` which is more like a name for an index, but that's what happens.

Comment: So it is like address of starting element of the `array` which we need to send and by `count` we decide how much after that address we are going to peak, right? and `MPI_INT` simply says `MPI_Send` to send integer.